# Extension of custom button on the BIM Model

Tags: autodesk-forge

In our platform, in the BIM Model we have tools in the bottom bar and others in the left and right sides.

We need to add them all to the bottom bar.

We need to create an extension for any custom button we add, so we can add them to the  tool bar at the bottom on the BIM Viewer instead of left or right sides. We can't control that for now. Is there any way to control it.

Comment: Not sure what viewer specifically are you referring to. The official [APS Viewer](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/Viewer3D/) uses a single toolbar (at the bottom) by default, and all custom buttons you create are added there. See the [Dashboards](https://tutorials.autodesk.io/tutorials/dashboard/) tutorial for more details on how to customize the UI.